# mysql with the date function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table containing a field name `dtt_date` and have values like 
`08/04/2010 22:15:00`. I want to display all the records with in this month (08, august), How to write a mysql query in my php page to display these record.
Does any one know this?

Please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting a date field in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006384/formatting-a-date-field-in-mysql)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412735/specific-date-format-in-mysql, more examples there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the date format in the table to be '2010-08-04 22:15:00', then you could run this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dtt_date, '%D %M %Y') as date FROM myTable
```

From there you would get something of this as a result, and then you can experiment with the date formatting.

```
+-----------------+
| date            |
+-----------------+
| 4th August 2010 | 
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE dtt_date>='2010-08-01' AND dtt_date<='2010-08-31';
```

In PHP:

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dtt_date>='2010-08-01' AND dtt_date<='2010-08-31'";
 $res = mysql_query($q);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
   var_dump($row);
 mysql_free_results($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, I'm sure there are easier methods to this. Not sure if your date format will be handeled by MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')) = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one method

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE month(dtt_date)='08' AND year=(dtt_date)='2010';
```